# Custom wordpress portfolio

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, portfolio

I'm making a portfolio page for a photographer. The photographer should be able to add new projects via wordpress. I am not really familiar with how wordpress uses the inputs for an "post" or "project" to create a new portfolio project.

Currently I have an intermediate knowledge of HTML and CSS. How would I be able to assign my own styles to content that is yet to be created? I figure this requires knowledge of PHP?

I understand this is a pretty general question and I apologise for my question is too vague. Searching for solutions has yet only given me plugin solutions.

Comment: use some plugin to add project

Comment: well yeah you need a little bit of knowledge about PHP, and of course wordpress itself. btw your question is too broad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create a custom WordPress template not only requires some basic PHP knowledge, but also [WordPress template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) knowledge. You can read all about them here.

I would suggest to use a theme instead. There are [countless](https://colorlib.com/wp/best-portfolio-wordpress-themes/) (the link is just an example) amazing portfolio themes, lots of them free and all of them responsive. If you want to go along with your current theme and use just a plugin to create those portfolio items, I suggest a plugin like [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/).

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed to know. Due to my newb account I can't upvote your answer... yet ;)